# Surreal numbers ordering and false inequality $1\le0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, surreal-numbers

Given numeric forms $x =\{ X_L \,|\, X_R\}$ and $y =\{ Y_L \,|\, Y_R\}$ of two [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) we say that $x \le y$ if and only if

- There is no $x_L \in X_L$ such that $y \le x_L$ and
- There is no $y_R \in Y_R$ such that $y_R \le x$.

According to this definition it seems to me that the comparison
$$
\{ \,| \,2 \, \} \le \{ \, -1 \, | \, \},
$$

which is a short for $\{\varnothing\,| \,\{2\} \} \le \{ \{-1\} \, | \, \varnothing \}$, should be automatically true, since $X_L = \varnothing$ and $Y_R = \varnothing$.
However, as far as I understand the surreal numbers, the expressions $ \{ \,| \,2 \, \}$ and $ \{ \, -1 \, | \, \}$ are valid numeric forms that represent numbers $1$ and $0$ respectively. Combining these two notions we arrive at
$$
1 \le 0,
$$
which seems to be absurd, since one expect surreal numbers to be compatible with the natural ordering.

Obviously, I am overlooking something. I would be very grateful if someone could point out a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both $\{|2\}$ and $\{-1|\}$ are actually equal to $0$, so your inequality is the unsurprising $0\le0$.

For reference, I'll show that $0\le\{-1|\}$. Both conditions "there is no $x_L$..." and "there is no $y_R$..." are vacuously satisfied. $\{|2\}\le0$ is analogous.

You may have confused things with $-2=\{|-1\}$ and $3=\{2|\}$. As we've just seen, it makes a big difference which set is empty.

Comment: Ah, this is how it works! A bit nonintuitive, but now I can see it. Thank you!